# subvert external function's `deparse(substitute())` without `eval`

Tags: r, metaprogramming, non-standard-evaluation

I'd like to wrap around the `checkmate` library's `qassert` to check multiple variable's specification at a time. Importantly, I'd like assertion errors to still report the variable name that's out of spec.

So I create `checkargs` to loop through input arguments. But to get the variable passed on to `qassert`, I use the same code for each loop -- that ambigious code string gets used for for the error message instead of the problematic variable name.

`qassert()` (via `vname()`) is getting what to display in the assertion error like `deparse(eval.parent(substitute(substitute(x)))`. Is there any way to box up `get(var)` such that that R will see e.g. 'x' on deparse instead?

At least one work around is `eval(parse())`. But something like `checkargs(x="n', system('echo malicious',intern=T),'")` has me hoping for an alternative.

```
checkargs <- function(...) {
   args<-list(...)
   for(var in names(args)) 
      checkmate::qassert(get(var,envir=parent.frame()),args[[var]])
      # scary string interpolation alternative
      #eval(parse(text=paste0("qassert(",var,",'",args[[var]], "')")),parent.frame())
} 

test_checkargs <- function(x, y) {checkargs(x='b',y='n'); print(y)}

# checkargs is working!
test_checkargs(T, 1)
# [1] 1

# but the error message isn't helpful. 
test_checkargs(1, 1)
# Error in checkargs(x = "b", y = "n") : 
#   Assertion on 'get(var, envir = parent.frame())' failed. Must be of class 'logical', not 'double'.
#
# want:
#   Assertion on 'x' failed. ...
```

Comment: `eval(substitute(qassert(x,spec), list(x=get(var),spec=args[[var]])), envir=parent.frame())` avoids string interpolation but  reports the value of  var instead of the variable name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`substitute()` with `as.name` seems to do the trick. This still uses `eval` but without string interpolation.

```
eval(substitute(
      qassert(x,spec),
      list(x=as.name(var),
          spec=args[[var]])), 
     envir=parent.frame())
```